# populate listview dynamically with data from an array

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to populate a ListView dynamically like this:

```
'for testing, arrPassed has two values("Ford" and "Chevy")
    Dim arrPassed = New String() {"Ford", "Chevy"}  
    Dim colcount As New ListViewItem
    colcount.Text = "count"
    Dim colcar As New ListViewItem
    colcar.Text = "car"
    Dim intCount As Int32 = 1

    For Each car As String In arrPassed
        colcount.SubItems.Add(intCount)
        colcar.SubItems.Add(car)
        intCount = intCount + 1
    Next
    carList.Items.Add(colcount)
    carList.Items.Add(colcar)
```

All I see are:

> count    car

When I want to see:

```
count    car
1        Ford
2        Chevy
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Thanks!

Comment: We have no idea what data is in the array so it is difficult to know what is "correct".   Are you trying to summarize?

Comment: Is `carList.View = Details`? And do you have columns for the subItems?

Comment: for testing, I just have two values hard-coded into the array("Ford" and "Chevy") .  I did that just so I know what is exactly in the array.

Comment: If you have one ford and one chevy, how/why would chevy get a count of 2?

Comment: @Plutonix that's just the count of the row...maybe I should change 'count' to 'row'

Comment: ...or `index`.  You havent really described a problem: how that that snippet not working?  As is, this is a bit too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a ListView to show columns, you need to set the View property to Details view, and add some column definitions to the Columns property. Both of these can be done in the properties pane in design view of the form with the ListView control selected.